# Where to get the Oracle Security Developer Tools

Tags: java, oracle, security

i want to use some Methods of the Oracle Security Developer Tools Crypto Java API.

For Example http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31017_01/security.1013/b25378/index.html.

But I didn´t found where i can get (download / buy) them.

Tell me I am stupid, but please tell me also, where i can get them.

I searched half a day in the Web and I always found the API reference but never a Link to download it.

Sorry, if it is obviously, but I don´t see it.

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393)

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, on the assumption that you have a valid Oracle installation, then [from the docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28196_01/idmanage.1014/b28165/security_engine.htm):

The Oracle Security Developer Tools are installed with Oracle Application Server in ORACLE_HOME.

If you don't have access to the install, ask your hosting team to get them for you. A few quick searches on the usual jar-finding sites all seem to indicate that the oracle security tools are definitely pay-for-play and aren't legally available outside of an oracle purchase.

Comment: Thank you.  We have Oracle installed on my machine but I was poking around on the web looking for the OSDT jar files.  They were right there, I just did not think to look in that area.